# When I type something in any website inside a form, it's hard to see

Tags: firefox

In Firefox, when I type something in any website inside a form, it's hard to see. I can see it but it's very faint.

[image: faint text]

This happens on almost every website. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you give an example website where this is happening. You can also try with google.com and see if the issue remains.

Comment: Almost every website

Comment: Even google? Can you upload a screenshot of the google home page with some typed text...

Comment: Folks, it's hard to find anything more on-topic here than Firefox in Ubuntu. The question isn't about a specific website, it's about Firefox's UI. I can only guess why anyone thinks it's off-topic but consider: Firefox is even in the default install! It exists on other OSes too [as does everything; if programs like Firefox were out then *nothing* would be on-topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14535). Even if we did [radically change](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17174) our policies, [`firefox` is in **main** and officially supported by Canonical](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't about Ubuntu, thus my close vote, but, open `firefox`, go to the `Menu`->`Edit`->`Preferences` page, select the `Content` tab, and change the value in `Fonts & Colours`.